# Sass extension to check if the input file exists

Tags: ruby, sass

I want to build an extension which shows if the input file exists.

SCSS example:

```
@mixin generate-font-face($name, $source, $weight, $style) {
    @font-face {
        font-family: $name;
        font-weight: $weight;
        font-style: $style;

        @if file_exists("#{$source}.ttf") == true {
            // include
        }
    }
}
```

My Ruby module:

```
module Sass::Script::Functions
     # Does the supplied image exist?
     def file_exists(source)
        return Sass::Script::Bool.new(File.exists?(source.value))
     end
end
```

My directory structure:

```
/scss/index.scss
/scss/font/droid.scss # << index.scss
/font/droid.ttf
/css/index.css # output
/lib/file.rb
```

Example call:

```
@include generate-font-face("Droid Sans", "../font/droid", normal, normal);
```

But my extension won't work.

Comment: You haven't provided any error text, so we have to guess. Probably it's a paths issue. You provide a path relative to your SASS project, while the Ruby script that runs you custom function is not located there.

Comment: There is no error message. The function returns `false`.

Comment: Have you seen the font helper mixins from Compass?  http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/helpers/font-files/